# Is it possible to retrieve Samsung Gear S3 watch pedometer and heart rate logs without using the Samsung S Health app on the phone/tablet

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, tizen, samsung-mobile-sdk, samsung-gear-s2

Say for some reason, maybe some kind of security constraints, you can "not" run the Samsung "S Health" app which talks to Samsung cloud servers etc. But you do want to access the History/Logs off of the Samsung "Gear S3 watch", so is that possible or does Samsung lock that data so only "their" S Health app can get it?

So is there a way to download the pedometer+heart-rate "statistics"/data that you can see on the Gear S3 watch without using Internet/cloud or the official "S Health App" from Samsung on your phone?

Problem is if you don't use Samsung's S Health app it seems the log statistics get lost after a while, that it doesn't store too much on the watch itself only the last couple weeks. I don't want to use S-Health on Phone but would like to keep periodically saving the pedometer+heart rate data from gear-s3 watch so that the older data doesn't get lost.

Or is the "only" way to save the stats from days and weeks for pedometer daily walking stats and heart-rate, is from doing a completely separate app yourself that counts steps using the sensor etc?

Or maybe there is some "hacky" way to do this and get existing data/logs that are on the gear s3 watch without using the Samsung S Health app on the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access historical data you are going to make a phone application. Samsung keeps the historical health data locked down and only accessible through an SDK  for Android Application. If you wanted to make an application that the user only interacts with through the watch you would still need a phone side companion application to interface to the Samsung Health service. The phone side application could run as a service  so that it is otherwise invisible to the user. From the user's perspective, it would be a watch application. A user would also need to grant your application access to the type of data that it needs to access (an application doesn't automatically have access simply from being on someone's phone). You can download and read more about the Samsung Health SDK from  this site http://developer.samsung.com/health

Comment: Thanks but can you please clarify if I am able to access the historical health data if I make a watch app and a phone app that does NOT use internet? just Bluetooth? I want to download the data without allowing Samsung Health to talk on the internet with Samsung Servers. I want to do everything with only Bluetooth working, no internet. Currently the data is on the watch only so basically I just want to extract the health data from the watch in any way that avoids using internet access.

Comment: You can't. If you want to access historical data you will need to use the phone SDK. Historical data is saved in a Knox container on the phone.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that, now if I didn't want "historical" data and just real-time pedometer and heart rate data, can I access those numbers from the existing Samsung health stuff running on the watch or must I write my own redundant watch app that also runs its own separate heart-rate readings and pedometer calculations? It seems to me it would be a waste of "battery-power" to have to do that separately instead of being able to just read the already taken data/readings.

Comment: You can use the Human Activity Monitor ( tizen.humanactivitymonitor ) to get the user's current heart rate and detect their steps as they are taking them.  There is a heart rate sample at https://developer.tizen.org/zh-hans/development/sample/web/Sensor/Heart_Rate_Monitor

Comment: @Joel Thanks I marked answered but I hope you reply to a new question about if/how I can avoid using "Samsung apps/servers/S-health" to transfer data from my Gear Watch app to my phone over Bluetooth or wifi etc "without"  Samsung servers in between. Like if internet is "blocked" completely and just direct communication between the two devices without using S-Health as intermediary.

Comment: Here's my related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450110/smart-watch-tizen-samsung-gear-s3-smartwatch-native-app-with-phone-companion-app