# Smart Watch Tizen Samsung Gear S3 smartwatch native app with Phone companion app over bluetooth

Tags: android, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app, samsung-galaxy-gear

I would like to know if it is possible to create Tizen native apps on Samsung Gear S3 (running Tizen) that make use of the Human Activity Monitor or other Samsung Api in a way that does NOT require using any internet but to directly transfer data gathered to my own Phone App over Bluetooth without Samsung having access to the communication between my watch and my phone. So I don't want to use Samsung Gear "Manager" or S-Health or other methods which I "think" would give Samsung potential access to the Data Stream sent from my custom Watch App to my custom Phone App that receives the data over Bluetooth.

( One reason I ask is I read at a link on developer.samsung.com forum someone say: "You should write your own wearable app to measure continous heart rate, and the app need to communicate with Android host app via SAP(Samsung Accessory Protocol) so that your Andorid  host app to be able to get coutinous heart rate data from a wearable device. So the app type should be companion type.
Remote sensor SDK does not support HRM." And if I am forced to use some "SAP" Samsung Accessory Protocol it sounds like it goes through Samsung Gear Manager or other method where Samsung can get a copy of the Data Stream? Or not true? )

That's the first part of the question, second question are there any Native examples of using the Hardware Sensors on the Samsung Gear S3 "directly" without using Samsung's own provided "Human Activity Monitor" Api etc?

Also, is the source code behind Samsung's Human Activity Monitor API and other APIs they provide, is the source code available to these SDK and APIs or is there plenty of "closed source" running on the Samsung Gear smartwatches?

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Tizen, you will be able to use [**Bluetooth**](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/connectivity-and-wireless/bluetooth) functionalities such as managing the local Bluetooth adapter, bonding, and exchanging data between Bluetooth-enabled devices instead of using SAP. The Bluetooth standard provides a **peer-to-peer (P2P)** data exchange functionality over short distance between compliant devices.

[image]

You can also use **[Pedometer](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/location-and-sensors/device-sensors#pedometer)** and **[Heart Rate](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/location-and-sensors/device-sensors#hrm_green)** sensor instead of using Human Activity Monitor(HRM) in Tizen Native app.
For all the available sensors api in Tizen go [here](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/location-and-sensors/device-sensors).

Comment: great, thanks, sorry for the late reply, just checked back in again now